# Good practise to split data over multiple databases?

Tags: mysql, database

I am designing a database for use in an information system. It will have data on customers, employees and items. Needless to say, the customers section alone has about a dozen tables.

I would like to know if it's bad practise to split this data over multiple DBs and then just refer amongst them, or if keeping them all in the same DB would be better.

So, rather having a single DB (e.g. **Company_DB**) with two dozen tables (e.g `CUS_DETAILS`, `EMP_DETAILS`, etc), would it be better to have two DBs (**Company_Cus, Company_Emp**) with the `CUS_DETAILS` in one and `EMP_DETAILS` in the other?

Regards.

Comment: depends on what you want to achieve? i think the whole problem is a bit unclear here.

Comment: IMHO, joining would be faster on a single database than across multiple ones...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Good practice" is one of those phrases that allows us to make our prejudices sound more important than they really are...

In general, you want to store things together that belong together. If you have a single information system, that runs everything for a business, and the entities you manage are related to each other - customers have orders, orders have sales people and products - you could argue they belong together. If, on the other hand, you notice that you have "islands" of tables that don't really link to any other tables, perhaps they don't belong together.

From a maintainability point of view, managing more databases means more back-ups, more maintenance routines, and more security profiles to manage.

From a readability point of view, hunting around different databases to find the table you're interested in is probably a bad thing - for instance, where there is a many-to-many join table between "customers" and "employees" - e.g. sales team - where does that table live? In the "customer" database, or "employee"?

From a reliability point of view, I'm not sure if you can enforce foreign key constraints across databases.

I can't really think of any benefits of doing this - so I would say it's a bad idea.

Comment: Many-to-many relations table (or matrix table) should be named, in your case, `customers_employees` (plural in alphabetical order) as per common naming conventions. :) This way you will never get lost in your 10000+ tables schema.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to have it all in one database, rather than having data scattered throughout several databases.

Personally I think the only reason to separate information in different databases would be to have systems or sub-systems, totally different from each other, on a single platform.

The amount of data will be the same, regardless of how many databases you use.

Answer (score 1):

> I would go for a single DB,unless it really not necessary to split
>   into multiple data sources a single DB is not limited to dozen of
>   tables.

There will be always a headache enough to manage multiple resources.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was more for readability purposes when doing DB maintenance but thanks, I'll just use a single database.

Comment: even if you have multiple client then also I would suggest you to use single DB with multiple clients specific data.

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing the databases on the same disk? If so, splitting it in different databases would give you no improvements at all. References among multiple databases are way slower than multiple tables in the same database.

A single db, however, will be faster and easier to maintain: Only one database to secure, only one database connection to manage in application, etc.

The reason for database to exists is to keep a group of related objects together so we can manage them accordingly (otherwise we would just create tables procs and views directly, without tying them to a database, and every table would have its own file, statistics, etc).

If you think putting the tables on the same database would get messy, maybe you need a better object-naming-pattern?

Bottom line: seems a really bad practice to me as it gives no advantage and lots of drawbacks.