# Looking for suggestions for planning out a potentially very large database (mysql)

Tags: mysql, database

I currently have a database which is already >15GB in size, and will grow to much larger. I'm not aiming to add in an extra table purely for "api" data that gets pulled in (which is related somewhat to the other tables data but only by a single ID reference).

I have some "api" data from external sources that gets imported and I've calculated it could grow to around 300GB in size. This data can be re-fetched and isn't as critical to be backed up, so in order to keep backups more manageable I thought *why not* put that api data into a different database?

However, after reading ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14936038/good-practise-to-split-data-over-multiple-databases)) it sounds like this is bad practice.

I just wanted to get some opinions on this. The API data is just JSON "mediumblob"s that get stored and could even potentially be stored as flat files instead, but I think maybe a secondary database for "more disposable" data is appropriate?

Thoughts/ideas/recommendations?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not be worried for a 300 GB database. As of todays standard that is not a large database, and with the correct indexes it will not be a problem. I would go a head with one database.

Comment: Well, my concern is database backups. It seems beneficial for me to not have to worry about backing up a section of the database that isn't too important?